# Users in ADGroup with direct reports

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I want a list of users in `ATL Users` that have direct reports.

**Part 1: Group Membership**

I can get the users in a group.

```
Get-ADGroupMember "ATL Users" | Where objectClass -eq "user"
```

**Part 2: Filter for Direct Reports**

I can get a list of users with direct reports, but very slowly (scans entire tree).

```
Get-ADUser -Filter "DirectReports -like '*'"
```

**Question**

How can I get the list of users in `ATL Users` then `-Filter` those users by if they have direct reports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is readily done with an LDAP filter using memberOf. If this is a one-off query and you know the group's distinguished name (cn=ATL Users,ou=groups,dc=domain,dc=gTLD in this example), you can use:

```
    get-aduser -LDAPFilter "(&(memberOf=cn=ATL Users,ou=groups,dc=domain,dc=gTLD)(directReports=*)(objectClass=user))"
```

If you will be running this query repeatedly, it would be best to get the group object from a search so directory restructuring won't break your query.

```
PS> $groupFQDN = (get-adgroup -identity "ATL Users").distinguishedName
PS> $groupFQDN
CN=ATL Users,OU=NewGroupsOU,DC=company,DC=gTLD
PS> get-aduser -LDAPFilter "(&(memberOf=$groupFQDN)(directReports=*)(objectClass=user))"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just pipe a `foreach` into `Get-ADUser -filter` after `Get-ADGroupMember`

Example:

```
Get-ADGroupMember "ATL Users" | Where-Object {$_.ObjectClass -eq "user"} | foreach {Get-ADUser $_.samaccountname -properties Name, DirectReports | Where-Object {$_.DirectReports -like "*"} |Select Name, DirectReports}
```